# I am stuck on how to create a User with a RefreshToken associated with it using Typescript-sequelize

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I have been trying to discover how to create with an association in Sequelize for several weeks now.

I want to do this: find a user by their id, then create a refresh token that is associated iwth that ID. here:

```
    public createToken = async (userId: number, t: string) => {
        const later = new Date();
        const forUser = await User.findOne({ where: { userId: userId } });
        if (!forUser) throw new Error("No user found for this id");
        const rtedUser = RefreshToken.create(
            {
                token: t,
                isActive: true,
                expires: later,
                users: [forUser],
            },
            { include: [User] },
        );

        return rtedUser;
    };
```

But I get the error

```
src/db/dao/refreshToken.dao.ts:21:17 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ token: string; isActive: true; expires: Date; users: User[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Optional<RefreshTokenCreationAttributes, "tokenId">'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'users' does not exist in type 'Optional<RefreshTokenCreationAttributes, "tokenId">'.

21                 users: [forUser],
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

how can I get by this error?

Here are my models:

User.ts

```
import { Optional } from "sequelize";
import { Table, Column, Model, HasMany, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, PrimaryKey } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { RefreshToken } from "./RefreshToken.model";

interface UserAttributes {
    userId: number;
    email: string;
    firstName: string;
}

interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "userId"> {}

@Table
export class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    userId!: number;

    @Column
    email!: string;

    @Column
    firstName!: string;

    @HasMany(() => RefreshToken, "tokenId")
    rts?: RefreshToken[];

    @CreatedAt
    @Column
    creationDate!: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column
    updatedOn!: Date;
}
```

RefreshToken.ts

```
import { Sequelize as S, Optional } from "sequelize";
import { BelongsTo, Column, CreatedAt, ForeignKey, Model, PrimaryKey, Table, UpdatedAt } from "sequelize-typescript";
import { User } from "./User.model";

interface RefreshTokenAttributes {
    tokenId: number;
    token: string;
    isActive: boolean;
    expires: Date;
}

interface RefreshTokenCreationAttributes extends Optional<RefreshTokenAttributes, "tokenId"> {}

@Table
export class RefreshToken extends Model<RefreshTokenAttributes, RefreshTokenCreationAttributes> {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    tokenId!: number;

    @Column
    token!: string;

    @Column
    isActive!: boolean;

    @Column
    expires!: Date;

    @BelongsTo(() => User)
    user!: User;

    @ForeignKey(() => User)
    @Column
    userId!: number;

    @CreatedAt
    @Column
    creationDate!: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column
    updatedOn!: Date;
}
```

I have read the docs for typescript sequelize but I don't find any description of how to do this. Doesn't make sense given that its an essential part of using SQL

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript

this also fails

```
 user: { ...forUser },
```

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `user: forUser`?

Comment: I think you're right but the docs say otherwise: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/ Ctrl + F "Now we can create a product with multiple tags in the following way" to see a contrarian example

Comment: Well if you think about it... a user *hasMany* refresh tokens (and by the way, why does a user have many refresh tokens?)... so why would a refresh token have many users? Why would you be passing an array of users to a refresh token? Basically, I think you've got your models switched around...

Comment: It should be: (a) find the user in the db and populate a User object with the data. I do that. Then (b) you should type `userVarName.createRefreshToken({})`. It's like that in my plain Sequelize + plain TS project, which has the "mixins" thing in Sequelize. However, Typescript-sequelize has no explanation of how to do that operation using its package. Hence I am stuck making stuff up using Sequelize's docs.

Comment: I found the singular section where typescript-sequelize's docs talk about `modelA.$add('b' /* instance */).then(/* ... */);` but it doesn't work either. I try to insert a payload to make a refresh token and get `Argument of type '{ token: string; isActive: boolean; expires: Date; user: User; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | string[] | number[] | Model<any, any> | Model<any, any>[]'` from the line `await forUser.$add("rt", p);`